# Using Laravel Form class to add the 'disabled' attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Using Laravel 4's Form class, we can create a list using

```
 {{ @Form::select('colors', Colors::all()), $color }}
```

**Question:** How can we add the attribute `disabled` using Blade without having to rewrite the clean Blade syntax into the usual ugly form?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just add `array('disabled')` in the end like:

```
{{ Form::select('colors', Colors::all(), $color, array('disabled')) }}
```

Comment: How do i add it to individual items in the array? I want some headers in the list.

Comment: @MaciejSwic, there is a more complete answer below now

Comment: how can i add disable to the option element in that select??

Comment: I have the same question as @MaciejSwic, how do I disabled individual options? How do I add styles to individual options?

Answer (score 19):

This should do the work.

```
 {{ @Form::select('colors', Colors::all()), array(
    'disabled' => 'disabled',
    'class'    => 'myclass'
    ) }}
```

Comment: This is a more flexible and useful answer than the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Though already answered, IMO both answers weren't neutral enough, so to avoid duplicates the arguments are
`@Form::select('name', $optionsArray, $selectedOption, ['disabled'])`.

So if you're prepopulating form with `@Form::model()` you should do `@Form::select('name', $optionsArray, null, ['disabled'])` - array with 'disabled' has to be 4th parameter.