# Add styles and disable individual options in a Laravel Form Collective HTML select

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

I'm trying to reproduce this HTML form using Laravel Collective's HTML select:

`<option value="Vehicles"style="background-color:#E9E9E9;font-weight:bold;" disabled="disabled"> - Vehicles - </option>`

This is what I have in my blade:

`{{ Form::select('subcategories', $subcategories, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) }}`

The document here is rather limiting:
https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#drop-down-lists and doesn't indicate if individual styles or if disabling is possible.

There is a similar question here on Stackoverflow

[Using Laravel Form class to add the 'disabled' attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739699/using-laravel-form-class-to-add-the-disabled-attribute)

where 'disabled' is discussed, but it seems for the whole select. There was in the comments section people who ask about individual items, but no clear answer.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will disable whole `select` element:

```
{!! Form::select('subcategories', $subcategories, null, ['disabled' => true, 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

**Update**

You want to disable some of the options. It's impossible, because [`select()` method doesn't have such functionality](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/5.3/src/FormBuilder.php#L538)

What you can do is to [create macro like this one](http://laravel.io/bin/2WWMN).

Comment: I don't want to disable the whole select. I want to disable individual items.

Comment: Oh. Then you can't do it, because there is no such functionality in `select()` method. What you can do is to create macro: http://laravel.io/bin/2WWMN